# XML xpath? filtering xml tags based on attribute NOT being in a list

Tags: xml, xpath

Trying to filter xml tags based on a list.

List example: filename list.txt

1
2
3
4
5
6

Sample XML

< id=1 />
< id=4 />
< id=11 />
< id=3 />
< id=23 />

Using XPath?  is it possible to write an xpath query that will filter the xml tags to leave only whats not in the list.txt?

output
< id=11 />
< id=23 />

Is this possible in an xpath statement?

Comment: We need to see the real structure of your XML

Comment: You cannot read a text file in xpath or xquery. If you transform your text file in a xml, you can use the fn:doc() function to load the new xml, then grab the values in sequence and use fn:exist(fn:index-of(sequence, value)) to test if the value is in the sequence. Check this link for xpath functions: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: What you provide as "XML" and as wanted output, isn't well-formed XML at all. Please, correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who offered feedback and suggestions.  I have figured out my own problem.  Please provide feedback on my solution to see if it can be made better.  Thanks..

My problem has to do with Nessus.  It's reports are terrible.  I was able to check out the .nessus file, ver2 and piece together the information in the tags that I needed.  I'll put it up here for other Nessus users who could use a similar report.

I needed a way to filter out plugin information from the report that was not important.  I decided the best way was to filter the plugins using xslt that I was also using to format the xml file to a useful tabular format for a spreadsheet app.  I decided to use a separate xml file to store tags containing unwanted Nessus plugins.  The structure for xml file was like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<exclude>
  <nessusPlugin>19506</nessusPlugin>
  <nessusPlugin>45590</nessusPlugin>
</exclude>
```

I followed the suggestion about looking into the 'document' function and eventually came up with this xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="excludedplugins" select="document('nessusExcludePluginList.xml')/exclude/nessusPlugin"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>
      Nessus Report, Targets: <xsl:value-of select="count(NessusClientData_v2/Report/ReportHost)"/> 
    </h2>
    <br/>High Risk Count: <xsl:value-of select="count(NessusClientData_v2/Report/ReportHost/ReportItem[risk_factor='High'])"/>
    <br/>Medium Risk Count: <xsl:value-of select="count(NessusClientData_v2/Report/ReportHost/ReportItem[risk_factor='Medium'])"/>
    <br/>Low Risk Count: <xsl:value-of select="count(NessusClientData_v2/Report/ReportHost/ReportItem[risk_factor='Low'])"/>
    <br/>Irrelavant Risk (Severity &lt; 2) Count: <xsl:value-of select="count(NessusClientData_v2/Report/ReportHost/ReportItem[@severity&lt;2])"/>
    <table border="1">    
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>DNS Name</th>
        <th>NetBios Name</th>
        <th>IP Address</th>
        <th>MAC Address</th>
        <th>Operating System</th>
        <th>Port</th>
        <th>Protocol</th>
        <th>Service Name</th>
        <th>n Plugin ID</th>
        <th>n Severity</th>
        <th>n Risk_Factor</th>
        <th>n Plugin Name</th>
        <th>n Plugin Family</th>        
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Plugin Output</th>
        <th>Synopsis</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="NessusClientData_v2/Report/ReportHost">
        <xsl:for-each select="ReportItem">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(@pluginID=$excludedplugins)">
              <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../@name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../HostProperties/tag[@name='netbios-name']"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../HostProperties/tag[@name='host-ip']"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../HostProperties/tag[@name='mac-address']"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../HostProperties/tag[@name='operating-system']"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@port"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@protocol"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@svc_name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@pluginID"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@severity"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="risk_factor"/></td>            
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@pluginName"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@pluginFamily"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>            
                <td><xsl:value-of select="plugin_output"/></td>            
                <td><xsl:value-of select="synopsis"/></td>            
              </tr>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>              
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hacked this together and came up with these solutions:
1.  To add the xml file with the unwanted plugin list:

```
<xsl:variable name="excludedplugins" select="document('nessusExcludePluginList.xml')/exclude/nessusPlugin"/>
```

1. To do the comparison with the excluded plugins:

Wasn't sure about comparison till I tried it.  It turns out that this works with all the items in the nodes.  What a deal!  What I haven't figured out is why this doesn't work:

```
<xsl:when test="@pluginID!=$excludedplugins">
```

The = operator will check with all the nodes but the != doesn't seem to work at all.  Good thing the 'not' function exists.

What I would like to do to make this better is see if there is a way to feed it the list of unwanted plugins with a straight list of plugin numbers instead of an xml file, like this:
58181
34252
34220
11219
10335
22964

I also think there maybe a more elegant solution that doesn't use the 'for each'.  Anyway, thanks for the help everyone.